# Like API Returns Who Given ID Likes - How To Get Who Likes a Given ID?

Tags: facebook, object, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Can you specify an object id, eg. a page, and find out how many likes it has, and who they are?  Seeing who a given object id likes isn't as useful for reporting purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook won't provide who likes a page via the API, probably most likely for privacy reasons.